# Error gradlew uploadArchives

Tags: genexus

Estoy actualizando QRScanner(GX17U5) y al ejecutar gradlew uploadArchives devuelve el siguiente error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':AdMobAds:compileReleaseAidl'.

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: Verificaria los requerimientos listados aquí https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample. En particular las variables GENEXUS_REPO y ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: agregue la variable GENEXUS_REPO que no la tenia,  pero sigue con el mismo error

Comment: usaste este formato "file:///C:/path/to/GX/Android/m2Repository" para la variable, con "file://" . Obtienes exactamente el mismo error ahora?

Comment: Si con file obtengo el mismo error